# Ambiguous use of 'object(forKey:)' in XCode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

I've updated my XCode to version 12.2 and project fails to compile. The errors are in the following lines (I extracted the problem string in a separate function `foo`):

```
func foo() {
    let mainBundleUrl = Bundle.main.bundleURL
    let settingsPropertyListUrl = mainBundleUrl.appendingPathComponent("Settings.bundle/Root.plist")
    if let settingsPropertyList = NSDictionary(contentsOf: settingsPropertyListUrl) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let settingsArray = settingsPropertyList.object(forKey: "PreferenceSpecifiers") as! NSMutableArray
        var registerableDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
        for i in 0 ..< settingsArray.count {
            if let key = (settingsArray.object(at: i) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "Key") as? String {
                if defaults.object(forKey: key) == nil {
                    let value = (settingsArray.object(at: i) as AnyObject).object(forKey: "DefaultValue")
                    registerableDictionary[key] = value as AnyObject?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error says:

> Ambiguous use of 'object(forKey:)'

Looks like it is a change in iOS SDK or Swift compiler. Can someone help to resolve this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's more a "Objective-C" litteraly translated into "Swift" instead of interpret the Objective-C into Swift, with all the Swift "logic". You should rewrite it. There are also `PropertyListSerialization` since, or simply getting rid of the `NSMutableArray`, `NSDictionary`, and doing more `if let`/`guard let`.

Comment: @Larme I know... This is a legacy code which broke since the XCode update.

Comment: Quick fix might be: `guard let setting = settingsArray.object(at: i) as [String: Any] else { return }`, and use `setting` instead of `(settingsArray.object(at: i) as AnyObject)`. But, Codable might be a better idea. Also, what does "PreferenceSpecifiers" looks like? Because, it could be simplified if it's a `[[String: Any]]`.

Comment: Thanks @Larme. It helped to solve the issue!

Comment: I have similar problem here...can help me aswell?
This is the code, develop for another programmer: if var value = (serverTriggersArray as AnyObject).object(forKey: attribute) {
    //...
    }     and  if let eventsArray = (serverTriggersArray as AnyObject).object(forKey: "automation_events") as? NSArray {
    //...
    }

Comment: @xhinoda You need to rewrite the code splitting long expressions in several, introducing new variables. That helped me.

Comment: I don't know if is ok, but i replace .object(forKey:) for value(forKey:) and the error go away.

Comment: @xhinoda Look's good :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Larme for the help!

The code started to compile once I rewrote it using `guard let`

```
func foo() {
    let mainBundleUrl = Bundle.main.bundleURL
    let settingsPropertyListUrl = mainBundleUrl.appendingPathComponent("Settings.bundle/Root.plist")
    if let settingsPropertyList = NSDictionary(contentsOf: settingsPropertyListUrl) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let settingsArray = settingsPropertyList.object(forKey: "PreferenceSpecifiers") as! NSMutableArray
        var registerableDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
        for i in 0 ..< settingsArray.count {
            guard let setting = settingsArray.object(at: i) as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let key = setting["Key"] as? String else { continue }
            if defaults.object(forKey: key) == nil {
                let value = setting["DefaultValue"] as AnyObject?
                registerableDictionary[key] = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```